# UDP multicast failing - NodeJS / Windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, udp, multicast

I am beating my brains out trying to get this to work. I read all the other answers related to NodeJS UDP on SO already, but to no avail. I am on Windows 10.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Uncaught Exception: Error: write ENOTSUP
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at ChildProcess.target._send (internal/child_process.js:654:20)
at ChildProcess.target.send (internal/child_process.js:538:19)
at sendHelper (cluster.js:751:15)
at send (cluster.js:534:12)
at cluster.js:509:7
at SharedHandle.add (cluster.js:99:3)
at queryServer (cluster.js:501:12)
at Worker.onmessage (cluster.js:450:7)
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (cluster.js:765:8)
at emitTwo (events.js:111:20)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
at process.nextTick (internal/child_process.js:744:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
at process._tickDomainCallback [as _tickCallback] (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

Here is my code:

```
let dgram = require('dgram'),
        server = dgram.createSocket('udp4'),
        multicastAddress = '239.255.255.250',
        multicastPort = 1900,
        myIp = '192.168.51.133';

    server.bind(multicastPort, myIp, function () {
        server.setBroadcast(true);
        server.setMulticastTTL(128);
        server.setInterface.getbyname(myIp);
        server.addMembership(multicastAddress, myIp);
    });

    //wait for incoming messages and print ip address
    server.on('message', function (data, rinfo) {
        console.log(new Date() + ' RECEIVER received from ', rinfo.address, ':');
        console.log(data.toString());
    });

    //Set up discovery message. Make sure to leave out any extra space in the message.
    var discover_message = new Buffer('M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 239.255.255.250:1900\r\nMan: ssdp:discover\r\nST: colortouch:ecp\r\n');
    server.send(discover_message, 0, discover_message.length, 1900, multicastAddress);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found an answer for this. The issue is due to being on Windows and using clusters in Node. The problem is on the server.bind call. Here is the correct, working code:

```
server.bind({port: 1900, exclusive: true}, function () {
        console.log('PORT BIND SUCCESS');
        server.setBroadcast(true);
        server.setMulticastTTL(128);
        server.addMembership(multicastAddress, myIp);
    });
```

The fix was to pass in the object {port: 1900, exclusive: true}. Source: https://github.com/misterdjules/node/commit/1a87a95d3d7ccc67fd74145c6f6714186e56f571